# How to run Messenger (of Facebook) and Instagram android apps (apks) in android emulator of Android Studio

Tags: android, instagram, emulation, messenger

All apks of Messenger and Instagram are being installed just fine! However, they all crash when I launch them. I tried many versions from the too old ones to the latest ones that were compatible with my android emulated version of android.

Keep in mind that Facebook app (apk) works like a charm in my emulator. Google Play cannot be installed as it seems like it is running without any icon to launch it.

**So, is there any way to run Messenger and Instagram in android emulator of Android Studio?**

Thank you very much!